# MissingMethodException is a service: "No signature of method"

Tags: grails

Having a really strange issue in a Grails service. I have a service thats setup like this:

```
package com.mydomain

import java.net.URLEncoder
import java.rmi.server.UID
import java.security.*

class EmailConfirmationService {
    def sendConfirmation(Person person) {}
}
```

And I'm calling it from a controller with `emailConfirmationService.sendConfirmation(person)`

When I startup the Grails app, it throws the following error:

```
MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/people/
No signature of method: mydomain.api.EmailConfirmationService.sendConfirmation() is applicable for argument types: (com.mydomain.Person) values: [name@mydomain.com]
```

All I have to do is save the EmailConfirmationService file, the watcher picks it up and recompiles, then it works great and never again throws that error.

Until I restart, then it errors until I save that file again.

I've tried the following but nothing has worked yet:

- clean build
- changed function name
- made sure person instance existed

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service states another package (`com.mydomain`) than the one in the error message (`mydomain.api`).  Please make sure, that the packages match and that the file is located in `grails-app/services/com/mydomain/EmailConfirmationService.groovy` (unless all of this is due to some obfuscation you did for SO)